# How can I make Google Voice calls using my Apple Address Book & Quicksilver?

Tags: mac, google-voice, quicksilver

There's got to be an easier way than copying and pasting phone numbers from my Quicksilver / Address Book.app look-up into the Google Voice web page.

Does anyone have any tips on how to make this easier?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but was looking for the same answer and saw this script, which is an interesting, direct approach: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090805155644746

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an app called Vocito (http://googlemac.blogspot.com/2008/11/vocito-voe-kee-toe.html), but it hasn't been updated since GrandCentral became GV. The closest I've come to what you want is the Firefox Google Voice Add-on: http://thatsmith.com/2009/03/google-voice-add-on-for-firefox

Answer (score 0):

Well, google voice  will import csv files, so if you can export them from your address book, you can import them.

Most things export csv (not everything, I had to screen scrape my address book for my sidekick (that is, select from the webpage, copy, paste into a spreadsheet, save as a csv, import that, and clean the results))

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking for my "ideal" Quicksilver solution.  Until I find/write that i'm using GV Connect which is a desktop widget that ties into your Address Book.  It's small and works well, I'm just not a big fan of desktop widgets in general.

You can download it from here:

http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/email_messaging/gvconnect_andreasamann.html